# Copying a smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

If smart contracts are completely open source and viewable to the public, then what stops someone from copying someone else's work to create an exact copy of their service? Is the value a blockchain company can provide completely tied to the UX/UI of their application using a smart contract?

I'm thinking of a company like this (https://www.wageth.com/contract). The code is viewable on their site and they make a small profit by taking a cut of the prize pot that people contribute to. From what I understand, there is nothing stopping a competitor creating an exact copy of this game while routing the profit to a different wallet or account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific example the value of the organization is based on the brand loyalty of the users, the number of users, the fees, and addition of new features as new games are started. While the contract is open source, if you were to copy the source and deploy it on the ethereum network yourself, it would have a very different address and you would have to convince people to use your contract over the creator's. You would either have to offer lower fees, build a better brand, add more features or do better advertising. Similar to other markets.

The contract listed above "needs" to be open source because it adds a layer of transparency to the game. The maintainer(s) need to assure the participants that the contract functions the way they say it does and the best way to do that is to publish the contract source.

You could take the contract from your example and deploy it on a test network, verify that it functions as described and then participate in their deployed contract. Keep in mind that open source doesn't always mean free to use. If the contract is not published with a license that gives you permission to copy or deploy it, you likely don't have the legal right to do so just because they published the source code on line. (I'm no lawer)

Not all contracts need to be open source, while the compiled bytecode is stored on the chain, the source is not. You could copy the bytecode of a deployed close source contract and redeploy it. However, not being able to provide the source or possibly not having a full understanding of how the contract works could make it difficult to convince users to use the contract at the address you deployed over the "official" deployment.